# How to fill in data frame based on vectors

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I have the following data.frame `data`:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=4, nrow=4))
colnames <- seq(from = 6, to = 3, by = -1)
names(data)<- sprintf("%.1f", colnames)
rownames <- seq(from=5, to=2, by=-1)
rownames(data) <- sprintf("%.0f", rownames)
```

I have two vectors, `a` and `b`:

```
a <- seq(11, 5, -1)
b <- seq(0, 30, 5)
```

`a` represents all possible sums that the column and row headers can take. For example, the northwest-most cell is `6+5=11`.

`b` represents the values that I want to be filled into the data.frame. The order corresponds to the order of `a`. For example, `data[1,1]` (row and column names sum to `11`) should take on value `0`. `data[1,2]` and `data[2,1]` should both take on value `5`.

How would I go about doing this?

My initial thought is to loop through all cells and check what their row+col name sum is and then check if this sum is in a and if so grab the position and then go to b and grab the value based on the position and then fill it in. Is this on the right track?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want a data.frame rather than to keep as a matrix in this example. There doesn't seem to be any advantage in doing so.
For your problem, I'd suggest looking at the 'outer' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
g <- outer(as.numeric(colnames(data)), as.numeric(rownames(data)), "+")

g <- matrix(sapply(1:length(g), function(x) b[which(a==g[x])]), nrow=4)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    5   10   15
#[2,]    5   10   15   20
#[3,]   10   15   20   25
#[4,]   15   20   25   30

#For a data frame:
g<- data.frame(g, row.names=rownames(data)); names(g) <- colnames(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

So (not tested), perhaps the following would work.

```
output <- outer(X=a, Y=b, FUN="+")
```

This will create an array/matrix. Of course then coerce to a data.frame if you need to, but I'm not sure why you do in the above example.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted when it's the core of the accepted solution posted a few minutes later.